# chrome.scripting.executeScript `runAt` property in Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I haven't found any mentions of the `runAt` property in the documentation for the new chrome.scripting.executeScript method.

These are potential properties for the `ScriptInjection` object: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection.

And these are potential properties for the `InjectionTarget` object, which is inside the `ScriptInjection` object: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-InjectionTarget.

There is no mention of `runAt` for `ScriptInjection` type.

But with tabs.executeScript we can specify `runAt` property.

How can we do this with manifest v3?

Comment: There's no way, see https://crbug.com/1217895. Why do you need it?

Comment: @wOxxOm for example, to override some constructors

Comment: You'll have to use MV2 until chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts supports `world: 'MAIN'` to inject in page context directly because there's no way in MV3 to do it before page starts loading currently, see https://crbug.com/1054624.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now `injectImmediately : true,`.

```
await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {
        tabId : await getCurrentTabId(),
        allFrames : true,
    },
    world: 'MAIN',
    injectImmediately : true,
    func: () => console.log('test')
});
```